# T-SQL List Dump Devices

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I create a dump device using T-SQL, like this:

```
EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'awesome', 'BOOMSAUCE.BAK';
```

If I try to create this device twice, the second time I run this query, it will fail, because the dump device `awesome` already exists. Is there a way to query the server for a list of dump devices which have been created?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for "BOOMSAUCE.BAK". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.backup_devices
```

I found it here: [Creating and using Dump Devices for Backups](http://sqlandme.com/2011/09/26/sql-server-creating-and-using-dump-devices-for-backups/)